# timer for slide show in iphone app development

Tags: iphone, slideshow

Hai,

I developed sample app for image slide show

Now i want to keep timer to the app.

It has to scroll the images for every 5 seconds

Please help me with sample code

Thanks
Basanth

Answer (score 0):

Its bad to ask for sample code. Because, you will not learn. If you see the documentation, along with required solution, you will get a chance to learn new things.
You can use UIImageVIew to show your images.
If you see the documentation for UIImageView, there is a property "animationImages" which will take an array of images. You can set "animationDuration" as well there.
That's it, your slide show is ready.